# Jstree - set_id function does not work

Tags: jquery, treeview, jstree

I im trying to set own ID to newly created node basing at value returned in ajax call from database. It looks like below. All functionalities works perfectly, eg.:

```
$("#mySelector").jstree(true).rename_node(data.node, newlyCreatedName);
```

But set_id still do not works properly. I based at official jstree API:
https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=set_id&f=set_id(obj, id)

```
$("#mySelector").jstree({ // my stuff 

})
.bind("create_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    // some logic
    $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            data: { parameters },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (output) {
                / some logic
                var setIdResult = $("#mySelector").jstree(true).set_id(data.node, output.newId);
                // set_id returns false :/
            }
})
```

Thanks in advance for help.

**EDIT**
It works :)

I made little mistake before firing set_id function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work - check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/jozegr3o/). Maybe you are not getting value in `output.newId`.

Or you can create a new node after successful ajax call - this way you can pass a new id straight to `create_node` function:

```
var parentNodeId = 'someId'; // use id of parent node, null or '#' for root level
$("#mySelector").jstree()
     .create_node(parentNodeId,  { "id" : newNodeId, "text" : "New node" }, "last");
```